# Why are wrist curls on bench often pointed to the sagital plane?

Tags: wrist

In every video I find about wrist extensions, there is a slight turn of the forearm into the sagital plane:

> [image]
>
> [Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=la-0c4ubkvs)

What is the logic behidn this?